# set_fact does not set ansible_facts?

Tags: ansible

in `test.yml` I have

```
- set_fact: hosts__test='2'

- debug: msg='ansible_facts={{ansible_facts}}'
```

When I execute play I get

```
TASK [test : set_fact] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [t2] => {"ansible_facts": {"etc_hosts__test": "2"}, "changed": false}

TASK [test: debug] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [t2] => {
    "msg": "ansible_facts={}"
}
```

Why `hosts__test` fact is not added to `ansible_facts` dictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `set_fact` you are setting fact for the host, these vars are accessible through `hostvars`.

you need to run:

```
 - debug: var=hostvars['hostname']['hosts__test']
```

In your case:

```
- debug: var=hostvars['t2']['hosts__test']
```